# Access current SharePoint Online user’s “Liked” & “Saved for later” docs/pages via Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

At the bottom of most pages/docs in SharePoint Online modern pages, there are “Like” and “Save for later” toggles.

I would like to be able to programmatically retrieve a list of things that were either “Liked” or “Saved for later” by the currently logged in user.

Is this something I can fetch using the Microsoft Graph or does SharePoint have something more readily available for reading this data?

Answer (score 1):

The ability to return the list of items of drive items that are followed is currently available in beta
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-list-following?view=graph-rest-beta

I believe that Like and save for later are different from follow. You may want to try this API to see whether they show up or not.